# Disable terminal broadcast messages in Linux

Tags: linux, openvpn, broadcast

I am relatively new user to Linux on the desktop and have recently started to connect to several work/personal VPNs using the following command:

```
sudo systemctl start openvpn-client@Personal
```

This all works fine, and I am successfully able to connect to my VPN. My problem is when my system asks for the VPN auth credentials (username/password), it does this in every single terminal I have open - not just the one I executed the command from. This is slightly annoying as it sometimes overwrites text/running commands in other sessions.

Is it possible to disable this? I have tried `mesg -n` with no luck.

```
$ uname -a
Linux t480s 4.18.10-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Sep 26 09:48:22 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```